# Directly pass variable content to command input expecting a filename

Tags: bash, gcloud

I'm trying to pass my environment secret to gcloud auth for a service account. I currently am doing it by creating a json file that gcloud can load.

```
printf "%s" "$GCP_KEY" >> GCP_KEY.json
gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=GCP_KEY.json
```

I would like to avoid creating a file with this secret.

Ideally, I would like something similar to:

```
printf "%s" "$GCP_KEY" | gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=/dev/stdin
```

Unfortunately,  gcloud uses the filename to determine whether the key is in json format or p12. Is there any way to make gcloud see it as a file with a filename ending in .json?

Comment: If you need to control the filename, the usual approaches (`--key-file=<(...)` &c) don't work and you really _do_ need a temporary file. It's worth a ticket upstream to poke them to fix this; depending on filenames is really bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

I took a look at the `gcloud auth activate-service-account` command [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/activate-service-account) and it says the --key-file param is required so how about deleting the file once the command ran successfully, you can do this as follow:

```
gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=GCP_KEY.json ; rm GCP_KEY.json
```